# Неккор. работа метода Disnake.py или моя тупость?

Tags: python, discord

Пишу бота на Disnake, столкнулся с весьма неочевидной проблемой, пытался решить различными способами. Кратко о проблеме: Ссылаюсь на сообщение на которое было сделано reply, получаю id сообщения. До этого момента всё работает идеально. Далее хочу получить список `reactions` под сообщением. Список реакций вроде появляется, но не совсем. Вместо желанного списка реакций я получаю невнятное `6️⃣`, а остальных 3-х реакций в списке просто нету. Как утверждает сама документация *reactions это - список реакций на сообщение*. А списка просто нету. Все `Intents`
выданы, библиотека импортирована корректно, вот кусок кода:

```
#Голосование
@bot.command(description='Добавляет дополнительный vote')
async def add_vote(ctx):
    msg = await ctx.fetch_message(ctx.message.reference.message_id)
    reaction = disnake.utils.get(msg.reactions)
    print(reaction)
```

screen message:
[image: screen message]

screen results:
[image: скриншот списка реакций]

Заранее thx за ответ! Первый раз на stackoverflow, надеюсь вопрос понятен :3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все верно — `discord.Message.reactions` — это свойство, представляющее список, содержащий реакции сообщения (`discord.Reaction`)

И для того, чтобы получить этот список, достаточно просто обратиться к этому свойству:

```py
msg = await ctx.fetch_message(ctx.message.reference.message_id)
reactions = msg.reactions
print(reactions)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```py
[<Reaction emoji='' me=False count=1>, <Reaction emoji='' me=False count=1>, <Reaction emoji='' me=False count=1>]
```

---

Если вам нужен именно список реакций в виде строк, то можно сделать так:

```py
reactions = [str(reaction) for reaction in msg.reactions]
print(reactions)
```

Получаем:

```py
['', '', '']
```

---

Метод `utils.get` используется для того, чтобы получить один конкретный элемент из коллекции. Вторым аргументом нужно указать одно конкретное свойство, например так:

```py
reaction = disnake.utils.get(msg.reactions, emoji='')
print(reaction)
```

Выхлоп:

Comment: Огромное спасибо за ответ!

Comment: @vkusniycat если ответ решил вашу проблему, могу я попросить вас отметить его как решение? :)

Comment: отметил, ещё раз спасибо!
)